# Resize LookupHoverDetail.getHover() window

Tags: visualforce, sfdc-styleguide

I need to resize or have flexible sizing on the pop-up window that opens with LookupHoverDetail.getHover().show().

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="pbt" value="{!DetailCensusList}" var="a">
     <apex:column>

        <a id="{!a.aDetCen.Id}" href="{!'/apex/PopupHistory?id='+a.aDetCen.Id}" 
          target="_blank"  
          onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!a.aDetCen.Id}').hide(); " 
          onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!a.aDetCen.Id}', '/apex/PopupHistory?id={!a.aDetCen.Id}').show();"
          onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!a.aDetCen.Id}').hide();" 
          onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!a.aDetCen.Id}', '/apex/PopupHistory?id={!a.aDetCen.Id}').show(); ">History</a>


     </apex:column>
```

Comment: `LookupHoverDetail` uses the MiniPageLayout and as such is guided by that configuration

Comment: @cropredy Yeah. That is the case.

Comment: I figured if I use HTML table in the child vf page. It works perfectly, the window resizes according to the size of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I figured if I use HTML table in the child vf page. It works perfectly, the window resizes according to the size of the table